# Where can I find out the differences between SQL Server and SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to find this out.  I asked a question about newsequentialid() and received an answer but there was no information backing it up.

Has anyone out there seen a place where I can see the capabilities or differences between the two databases and in particular the latest differences?

Comment: A google search for "sql server vs sql azure" returns a pretty impressive list of sites with this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the latest on Azure SQL Database here : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/. This should give you a good idea about what features currently exist in Azure SQL DB V12.

Additionally, you can find differences between Azure SQL DB and SQL Server in a VM here : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/

This one http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.comparison-of-sql-server-with-azure-sql-database.aspx is a slightly out-of-date page with comparison between Azure SQL DB and SQL Server on-prem, but has some useful basic differences.